# Difference between "joinpath" and "/" in Pathlib

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

Is there a difference between `joinpath` and the `/` operator in the `pathlib` module? The documentation doesn't ever compare the two methods. Essentially are there any cases where these two are different?

Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

foo = Path("some_path")
foo_bar_operator = foo / "bar"
foo_bar_joinpath = foo.joinpath("bar")

foo_bar_operator == foo_bar_joinpath
# Returns: True
```

Comment: as per my knowledge, you can use either interchangeably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b8544e18e61a0f4a873b3f4b4b2211822584b63f/Lib/pathlib.py#L845-L857) confirms this:

```py
    def joinpath(self, *args):
        """Combine this path with one or several arguments, and return a
        new path representing either a subpath (if all arguments are relative
        paths) or a totally different path (if one of the arguments is
        anchored).
        """
        return self._make_child(args)

    def __truediv__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._make_child((key,))
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented
```

Note you can pass multiple arguments to `joinpath` e.g. `a.joinpath(b, c, d)`. The equivalent for `/` would be `a / b / c / d`.